# Minimize click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(this).click(function() {
    clicked($(this));
});
```

How do I minimize this code to one line?

Tried this - doesn't work:

```
$(this).click(clicked(this));
```

It will be used then like this:

```
function clicked(element) {
    element.css('...');
        // some other code
}
```

Comment: Well, `$(this).click(function(){clicked($(this));});`... but seriously, why?

Comment: @Juhana because of the methods interpolation

Comment: Could you give an example? I don't know what method interpolation means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `clicked` function directly:

```
$(this).click(clicked);
```

but you'll need to change your `clicked` function to wrap the element.

```
function clicked() {
    $(this).do("whatever")
}
```

---

*Regarding your updated question*, you can have `clicked` return a function if you want.

```
function clicked(element) {
    return function() {
        element.css('...');
        // some other code
    }
}
```

So then you can do this:

```
$(this).click(clicked($(this)));
```

But I'd personally change your `clicked` function to work like the first version.